# Deleting a many to many relationship

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i have come across other posts with this same question that also went unanswered but not giving up. I'm making a D&D-related project and i have Encounters and Creatures, these have a many to many relation through EncounterCreatures.

Model Creature:

```
    public ICollection<EncounterCreatures> Encounters { get; set; }
    //Unshadowing
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
```

Model Encounter:

```
    public ICollection<EncounterCreatures> Creatures { get; set; }
    //Unshadowing
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
```

Model EncounterCreatures:

```
    public int CreatureId { get; set; }
    public int EncounterId { get; set; }
    public Encounter Encounter { get; set; }
    public Creature Creature { get; set; }
```

Related DBContext snippets:

```
    //Creatures
    modelBuilder.Entity<Creature>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Creature>().HasMany(e => e.Encounters); //EncounterCreatures

    //Encounter
    modelBuilder.Entity<Encounter>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Encounter>().HasMany(ec => ec.Creatures).WithOne(e => e.Encounter).HasForeignKey(e => e.EncounterId)
        //.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    //Composite Keys
        modelBuilder.Entity<EncounterCreatures>().HasKey(ec => new { ec.EncounterId, ec.CreatureId });
```

**If i do not specify .OnDelete NoAction i get this error and cannot create DB:**
*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_EncounterCreatures_Encounters_EncounterId' on table 'EncounterCreatures' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

**But then i cannot delete my Encounters because i will get this error:**
*System.InvalidOperationException:
The association between entity types 'Encounter' and 'EncounterCreatures' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable.
If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.*

**I do want to remove EncounterCreatures when the Encounter is removed so i want to setup cascade deletes but that leads me back to the first error.**

- Edit for Gert Arnold:

  ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<Character>(u => u.Characters).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<Encounter>(u => u.Encounters).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<Creature>(u => u.Creatures).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);
  ```

User Model:

```
public ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
public ICollection<Encounter> Encounters { get; set; }
public ICollection<Creature> Creatures { get; set; }
```

Comment: You only get this error if there are more relationships than the two you show.

Comment: Okay there is one more relationship that interacts with Encounters and Creatures and it is User which gets the same error upon deletion as Encounter. Adding it to post.

There's plenty other models and relations too but these do not interact with any of the above nor do they have issues, i don't think they are also needed?

Comment: So there are multiple cascade paths from `User` to `EncounterCreatures`. You need to choose one key that's not cascading.